# React Virtualized - Table Example - How do I make it work?

Tags: react-virtualized

I've been struggling to make [this react virtualized table example](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Table) work & seriously starting to doubt my sanity. I've created a react app and I'm just trying to render the example table inside App.js with this:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        var data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
        return (
            <TableExample
                list={data}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

React keeps saying `list` isn't defined - it seems obvious I'm not getting the data into the component the right way. I haven't been able to understand the example code, what props need to be passed in and what they should be named. Sorry for the stupid question but I've been stuck forever not knowing where else to find an answer. The table example code is below:

```
/** @flow */
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  ContentBox,
  ContentBoxHeader,
  ContentBoxParagraph,
} from '../demo/ContentBox';
import {LabeledInput, InputRow} from '../demo/LabeledInput';
import AutoSizer from '../AutoSizer';
import Column from './Column';
import Table from './Table';
import SortDirection from './SortDirection';
import SortIndicator from './SortIndicator';
import styles from './Table.example.css';

export default class TableExample extends React.PureComponent {
  static contextTypes = {
    list: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List).isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    const sortBy = 'index';
    const sortDirection = SortDirection.ASC;
    const sortedList = this._sortList({sortBy, sortDirection});

    this.state = {
      disableHeader: false,
      headerHeight: 30,
      height: 270,
      hideIndexRow: false,
      overscanRowCount: 10,
      rowHeight: 40,
      rowCount: 1000,
      scrollToIndex: undefined,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      sortedList,
      useDynamicRowHeight: false,
    };

    this._getRowHeight = this._getRowHeight.bind(this);
    this._headerRenderer = this._headerRenderer.bind(this);
    this._noRowsRenderer = this._noRowsRenderer.bind(this);
    this._onRowCountChange = this._onRowCountChange.bind(this);
    this._onScrollToRowChange = this._onScrollToRowChange.bind(this);
    this._rowClassName = this._rowClassName.bind(this);
    this._sort = this._sort.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      disableHeader,
      headerHeight,
      height,
      hideIndexRow,
      overscanRowCount,
      rowHeight,
      rowCount,
      scrollToIndex,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      sortedList,
      useDynamicRowHeight,
    } = this.state;

    const rowGetter = ({index}) => this._getDatum(sortedList, index);

    return (
      <ContentBox>
        <ContentBoxHeader
          text="Table"
          sourceLink="https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Table/Table.example.js"
          docsLink="https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md"
        />

        <ContentBoxParagraph>
          The table layout below is created with flexboxes. This allows it to
          have a fixed header and scrollable body content. It also makes use of{' '}
          <code>Grid</code> for windowing table content so that large lists are
          rendered efficiently. Adjust its configurable properties below to see
          how it reacts.
        </ContentBoxParagraph>

        <ContentBoxParagraph>
          <label className={styles.checkboxLabel}>
            <input
              aria-label="Use dynamic row heights?"
              checked={useDynamicRowHeight}
              className={styles.checkbox}
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={event =>
                this._updateUseDynamicRowHeight(event.target.checked)
              }
            />
            Use dynamic row heights?
          </label>

          <label className={styles.checkboxLabel}>
            <input
              aria-label="Hide index?"
              checked={hideIndexRow}
              className={styles.checkbox}
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({hideIndexRow: event.target.checked})
              }
            />
            Hide index?
          </label>

          <label className={styles.checkboxLabel}>
            <input
              aria-label="Hide header?"
              checked={disableHeader}
              className={styles.checkbox}
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={event =>
                this.setState({disableHeader: event.target.checked})
              }
            />
            Hide header?
          </label>
        </ContentBoxParagraph>

        <InputRow>
          <LabeledInput
            label="Num rows"
            name="rowCount"
            onChange={this._onRowCountChange}
            value={rowCount}
          />
          <LabeledInput
            label="Scroll to"
            name="onScrollToRow"
            placeholder="Index..."
            onChange={this._onScrollToRowChange}
            value={scrollToIndex || ''}
          />
          <LabeledInput
            label="List height"
            name="height"
            onChange={event =>
              this.setState({height: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) || 1})
            }
            value={height}
          />
          <LabeledInput
            disabled={useDynamicRowHeight}
            label="Row height"
            name="rowHeight"
            onChange={event =>
              this.setState({
                rowHeight: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) || 1,
              })
            }
            value={rowHeight}
          />
          <LabeledInput
            label="Header height"
            name="headerHeight"
            onChange={event =>
              this.setState({
                headerHeight: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) || 1,
              })
            }
            value={headerHeight}
          />
          <LabeledInput
            label="Overscan"
            name="overscanRowCount"
            onChange={event =>
              this.setState({
                overscanRowCount: parseInt(event.target.value, 10) || 0,
              })
            }
            value={overscanRowCount}
          />
        </InputRow>

        <div>
          <AutoSizer disableHeight>
            {({width}) => (
              <Table
                ref="Table"
                disableHeader={disableHeader}
                headerClassName={styles.headerColumn}
                headerHeight={headerHeight}
                height={height}
                noRowsRenderer={this._noRowsRenderer}
                overscanRowCount={overscanRowCount}
                rowClassName={this._rowClassName}
                rowHeight={useDynamicRowHeight ? this._getRowHeight : rowHeight}
                rowGetter={rowGetter}
                rowCount={rowCount}
                scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
                sort={this._sort}
                sortBy={sortBy}
                sortDirection={sortDirection}
                width={width}>
                {!hideIndexRow && (
                  <Column
                    label="Index"
                    cellDataGetter={({rowData}) => rowData.index}
                    dataKey="index"
                    disableSort={!this._isSortEnabled()}
                    width={60}
                  />
                )}
                <Column
                  dataKey="name"
                  disableSort={!this._isSortEnabled()}
                  headerRenderer={this._headerRenderer}
                  width={90}
                />
                <Column
                  width={210}
                  disableSort
                  label="The description label is really long so that it will be truncated"
                  dataKey="random"
                  className={styles.exampleColumn}
                  cellRenderer={({cellData}) => cellData}
                  flexGrow={1}
                />
              </Table>
            )}
          </AutoSizer>
        </div>
      </ContentBox>
    );
  }

  _getDatum(list, index) {
    return list.get(index % list.size);
  }

  _getRowHeight({index}) {
    const {list} = this.context;

    return this._getDatum(list, index).size;
  }

  _headerRenderer({dataKey, sortBy, sortDirection}) {
    return (
      <div>
        Full Name
        {sortBy === dataKey && <SortIndicator sortDirection={sortDirection} />}
      </div>
    );
  }

  _isSortEnabled() {
    const {list} = this.context;
    const {rowCount} = this.state;

    return rowCount <= list.size;
  }

  _noRowsRenderer() {
    return <div className={styles.noRows}>No rows</div>;
  }

  _onRowCountChange(event) {
    const rowCount = parseInt(event.target.value, 10) || 0;

    this.setState({rowCount});
  }

  _onScrollToRowChange(event) {
    const {rowCount} = this.state;
    let scrollToIndex = Math.min(
      rowCount - 1,
      parseInt(event.target.value, 10),
    );

    if (isNaN(scrollToIndex)) {
      scrollToIndex = undefined;
    }

    this.setState({scrollToIndex});
  }

  _rowClassName({index}) {
    if (index < 0) {
      return styles.headerRow;
    } else {
      return index % 2 === 0 ? styles.evenRow : styles.oddRow;
    }
  }

  _sort({sortBy, sortDirection}) {
    const sortedList = this._sortList({sortBy, sortDirection});

    this.setState({sortBy, sortDirection, sortedList});
  }

  _sortList({sortBy, sortDirection}) {
    const {list} = this.context;

    return list
      .sortBy(item => item[sortBy])
      .update(
        list => (sortDirection === SortDirection.DESC ? list.reverse() : list),
      );
  }

  _updateUseDynamicRowHeight(value) {
    this.setState({
      useDynamicRowHeight: value,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Not yet, I've begun building my own version of it with as few dependencies as possible but haven't quite finished. @shinzou

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at some previous questions, it seems that the example is using some components that are not included inside dist package. Thats probably why you are getting undefined error.

Here is the most basic example of Tables in react virtulized:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Column, Table } from 'react-virtualized';
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'; // only needs to be imported once

// Table data as an array of objects
const list = [
  { name: 'Brian Vaughn', description: 'Software engineer' }
  // And so on...
];

// Render your table
ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    width={300}
    height={300}
    headerHeight={20}
    rowHeight={30}
    rowCount={list.length}
    rowGetter={({ index }) => list[index]}
  >
    <Column
      label='Name'
      dataKey='name'
      width={100}
    />
    <Column
      width={200}
      label='Description'
      dataKey='description'
    />
  </Table>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

When learning new library, its always best to start with the most simple example then expand on it. Here is the link to the [full table docs.](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the example is that in order for `contextTypes` to work, the parent component needs to define corresponding `contextTypes` and a `getChildContext` function.

In the parent component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    list: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List).isRequired
  };

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      list
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <TableExample />;
  }
}
```

Mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/873); see lines [48-53](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/demo/Application.js#L48-L53) and [68-76](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/demo/Application.js#L68-L76) of the react-virtualized demo Application.js.